# How to add animation on open of a Jquery SimpleModal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, simplemodal

The animation-enabled example in the SimpleModal site has this animation:

```
1. Fade in the overlay
2. Slide down the modal div
```

This is the code:

```
$("#the-div").modal({
onOpen: function (dialog) {
    dialog.overlay.fadeIn('fast', function () {
        dialog.data.hide();
        dialog.container.show('fast', function () {
            dialog.data.slideDown('fast');
        });
    });
}});
```

I want this animation instead:

```
1. Just display the modal
2. Fade in the overlay
```

Alas, simply removing the 2nd parameter of `dialog.overlay.fadeIn()` from the code above doesn't work. I also tried removing the parameters of `dialog.container.show()`, also changing it to `dialog.container.open()`. I've tried other combinations of the code, to no avail.

How do I achieve the animation that I wish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$("#the-div").modal({
  onOpen: function (dialog) {
    dialog.data.show();
    dialog.container.show();
    dialog.overlay.fadeIn('fast');
  }
});
```

Since you just want to display it, remove the callbacks altogether and just show the `modal` and kick off a [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) on the overlay at the same time :)

Comment: @Obay: Looks like `dialog.data` is hidden by default as well, answer's updated, give it another shot :)

Comment: @Obay: It's the reference the the element inside the modal, where `.container` refers to the `<div>` that wraps it (that SimpleModal creates), it's there for display, positioning, etc.